# Angular project - Working fine on local server but not on github

Tags: angular, github

My angular project is working fine on local server . But when I am hosting it through github then it is not working.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { XyzService } from './xyz.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
export class AppComponent {
 name:string;
 dictData:any;


constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private xyzService: XyzService, ) {}

getData() {
  this.xyzService.getDictonaryData(this.name).subscribe(
    data => {

        this.dictData = data;
          console.log(this.dictData);
          } ,

      error => {
          console.log("some error occured");
          console.log(error.errorMessage);
      }
  );

  }}
```

xyz.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';



 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
 })
  export class XyzService {
  word: String = "aardvark";
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
       console.log(err.message);
      return Observable.throw(err.message);
  }
   getDictonaryData(name?): any {
       if(name){
           this.word = name
       }
    let myResponse = this._http.get('/oxfordapi/' + this.word);
   return myResponse;

   } 
 }
```

app.component.html

```
<input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
<button (click)="getData()"> Get Data </button>

<div class="row" *ngIf="dictData">
<h2>{{dictData["results"][0]["lexicalEntries"][0]["entries"][0]["senses"][0]["definitions"]}}

</h2>
</div>
```

proxy.config.cli

```
 {
"/oxfordapi": {
  "target": "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/",
  "secure": true,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "app_id": "4ebd*****1",
    "app_key": "7d0740a12******bbc66907835843d6f"
  },
  "pathRewrite": {"^/oxfordapi" : ""}
}
   }
```

Finally I have used `ng build --prod` and uploaded the dist file on github .When I am hosting it through github it is giving error

> "polyfills.2341d85fe336aa23ce7f.bundle.js:1 o/oxfordapi/hi 404 ()" .

But when I am running my project on local server(localhost:4200), then it is working fine.

Comment: The proxy configuration is intended to proxy calls when running the dev server via `ng serve`, not with `ng build --prod`

Comment: I am using ng build --prod to generate dist file that i can upload on github for project hosting . although for running my file on local server i have used 'ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json' .

Comment: what errors do you get when running on the server?

Comment: "polyfills.2341d85fe336aa23ce7f.bundle.js:1 o/oxfordapi/hi 404 ()" .. I guess if we create  'proxy.config.cli' , then it will work only on local server . But how to make it host through github ??

Answer (score 0):

Proxy configurations are for development server only (ie `ng serve`).

You'll want to put your API urls in the environments, (ie put the production URL in `environments.prod.ts` and import envrionments from the service, (ie `import { environment } from '../../environment';`). It's important that you import the base/default `environment`, as the angular cli compiler will inject the correct environment file based on the --environment flag, which is `prod` by default when you run `ng build --prod`. You can override it with `ng CMD -e ENV` where cmd is serve, test, e2e, build, etc and ENV is the name and suffix of the environment.

**NB: This answer assumes you are using angular-cli**